# Prove that a quadratic equation has no roots in a congruence class

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, legendre-symbol

I have to show that $(E):x^2+12x-37 \equiv 0\;mod\;p$ where $p=421 \in \mathbb{P}$ have solutions, or not.

I would like to double check if my reasoning is correct. There is something that I feel uneasy about, although I am not sure why exactly.

Here's what I have done:

---

We find the discriminant and roots of $(E)$:

$\delta = 12^2 - 4 \cdot (1) \cdot (-37) = 292 > 0$

Therefore, $(E)$ has two real solutions. We are going to show that these two real solutions are not in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and that therefore, the equation has no solutions.

We have $x_i = \frac{-12 + (-1)^i \sqrt{\delta}}{2}$ where $i = 0, 1$

$x_0^2 = 109 - 12 \cdot \sqrt{73}$

$x_1^2 = 109 + 12 \cdot \sqrt{73}$

Observe that, $x_1^2, x_2^2 \notin \mathbb{Z}_{p}$

$\therefore (E)$ has no solutions modulo $p$

---

I suspect that this could be extended to say that $\delta$ has to be a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

Also, this question was given in an assignment about Legendre and Jacobi Symbols.

Please do not spoil the answer, or use a formula that would make the problem trivial. I am trying to develop my intuition on the topic. If it is really necessary, please put a "warning". :-)

Thank you,

Comment: This is certainly not true: We have $x^2 + 12 x - 37 \equiv x^2 - 1 \equiv (x + 1)(x - 1) \bmod 3$, so $\pm 1$ are solutions modulo $3$. In general one cannot do algebra over $\Bbb R$ and then "reduce" modulo $p$.

Comment: (In fact, with even less thought, we can see that $x^2 + 12 x - 37 \equiv (x + 12) x \bmod 37$.)

Comment: I don't think it's good intuition to start with real solutions and then try to see whether they're "in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$"; since $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R$, that doesn't really make sense. Instead, I suggest you carefully follow the process you would use to solve a quadratic over $\Bbb R$, and then, at the step where you take a square root, figure out when that is possible in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (a step that is trivial in $\Bbb R$).

Comment: @GregMartin If I understand correctly, this means checking if $b^2 - 4 \cdot a \cdot c$ is a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ right?

Comment: @Travis sorry, I should have precised that $p=421$. I understand what is my mistake though, thank you. (Also edited the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED QUESTION: Apparently we also know $p=421.$

$$ x^2 + 12 x - 37 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
add $73=73.$
$$ x^2 + 12 x + 36 \equiv 73 \pmod p  $$
$$ (x+6)^2 \equiv 73 \pmod p  $$
let $w = x+6$
$$ w^2 \equiv 73 \pmod p  $$

This has solutions for some $p$ but not others.